# IDLE Problem issue, and Throttle Body Specifications Honda Civic LX 1998

Tags: throttle, throttle-body

Where can I find the throttle body specifications for a Honda Civic Lx 1998, I am searching and I get different results? It is producing an issue in accelerating, and tachometer the dial keeps going up and locks up the transmission. I believe this throttle body replacement might fix the problem, but since I new to the stack I would like to care to know what you think. The Throttle Body was checked and thought to be the problem since there was gunk in the cable.

The tachometer the one that is on the left of the speedometer. The car is accelerated when the car is left idle too long, and it happens to lock the transmission, and it can switch to drive or to anything. When it is in park it's accelerated alot.

Comment: Why do you think the throttle body is causing this?

Comment: @HandyHowie Because we replaced the idle air control valve. The Problem persists.

Comment: @HandyHowie Let me edit my question.

Comment: I would check all the wiring & connections, ‘98 is old for wiring

Comment: I can’t see how the throttle body would make the tachometer behave erratically, or lock their transmission.  Can you describe the symptoms more?

Comment: I could possibly see the crank position sensor causing issues like this.

Comment: @HandyHowie the car is physically accelerated the meter is not the problem its shows up on the meter, and it can be heard, and yes that part got replaced too as well before. I really appreciate the help.